# Undecorated window using eclipse plugin classes

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to create a window without close/minimize/maximize and title bar. But I'm not able to find a way. In AWT, there is a method [setUndecorated()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29). But I don't know how to do it when developing eclipse plugin.

Right now I've window like this:[image]
But I wanted to make like this:[image]

How do we make it undecorated?
Here is my code:

```
 Display myDisplay = new Display();
 Shell myShell = new Shell(myDisplay);
```

Comment: Have you checked the SWT libraries?

Comment: No it is not `JFrame`, I'm using `org.eclipse.swt.widgets` package.

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you want, you just need to pass in the appropriate style flags when creating your Shell object. There is a constructor variant that takes a style int. Take a look at javadoc in Shell class for listing of all available switches and their semantics.

Comment: Probably SWT.TOOL or SWT.NO_TRIM

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for what is called a lightweight dialog (or what I call, I don't know if this is an official name for it).  An example of this is the TipOfTheDay dialog in the Spring Tool Suite.  [See the entire source here.](https://github.com/SpringSource/eclipse-integration-commons/blob/master/org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.ui/src/org/springsource/ide/eclipse/commons/ui/tips/TipOfTheDayPopup.java)

The key parts of the class are that it subclasses `org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.PopupDialog` and that the super class is called like this:

```
super(parentShell, PopupDialog.INFOPOPUPRESIZE_SHELLSTYLE | SWT.MODELESS, false, true, true, false, false,
            "Spring Tool Tips", null);
```

See the `PopupDialog` source code for more options.

Comment: Hi, I checked its source code, and tried running. We cannot add UI objects into it. It looks like documentation viewer tooltip

Comment: What do you mean by UI objects?  You can create a PopupDialog and add any SWT widgets you want to it.

Comment: Or at least describe what you tried to do, but it didn't work.